# Unable to open camera from open cv2 in Python (Mac OS)

Tags: python, opencv

I am unable to open the camera from open cv. On executing the code just the camera light turns on but no camera is shown. This is happening on my mac.

```
import cv2
video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
if video.isOpened():
    while True:
        check, frame = video.read()
        if check:
            cv2.imshow('Color Frame', frame)
            key = cv2.waitKey(50)
            if key == ord('q'):
                break
        else:
            print('Frame not available')
            print(video.isOpened())
else:
    print("video not opened")
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that with the latest MacOS, the OS is restricting your app from accessing the camera. I used the latest iterm2 and it seems to work well in my case. I had to allow iterm2 to use the camera:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXc0Y.png

Then, I could get the frames and write them to the disk:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
if video.isOpened():
    for i in range(int(1e12)):
        check, frame = video.read()
        if check:
            cv2.imwrite(f'{i}.png', np.array(frame))
        else:
            print('Frame not available')
            print(video.isOpened())
else:
    print("video not opened")
```

PS: If your program is rejected from using the camera you should receive a signal like this:

`Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)`

Comment: Getting below error on running form iterm

objc[13448]: Class RunLoopModeTracker is implemented in both /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/QtCore (0x10d4a77f0) and /opt/anaconda3/lib/libQt5Core.5.9.7.dylib (0x12367da80). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
QObject::moveToThread: Current thread (0x7fe5e0d48750) is not the object's thread (0x7fe5e0f3a140).
Cannot move to target thread (0x7fe5e0d48750)

Comment: You might be loading two sets of Qt binaries into the same process. Check that all plugins are compiled against the right Qt binaries. Export DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=1 and check that only one set of binaries are being loaded.
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "cocoa" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: cocoa, minimal, offscreen.

Abort trap: 6